# Multiple Email Addresses, One User

Tags: user-meta

I'm trying to allow a user to have multiple email addresses associated with their account. `update_user_meta()` will not work because it will overwrite the current email. `add_user_meta()` wouldn't work either because it would duplicate the entry, even if it is the same email address.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `update_user_meta()` and `add_user_meta()`, just store all the email addresses in an array in a new field. If you have a requirement, such as preventing duplicates, run a validation function that checks for that before updating the database.

Comment: Is there some validator function native to wordpress, similar to `update_user_meta()` checking for duplicate keys. Is there something that looks for the value?

Comment: Not to WordPress, but you can accomplish that particular validation with PHP's `array_unique` function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php